# How can I insert different columns of two different tables from a single trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In oracle SQL, I want to use a single trigger to update two columns `(A,B)` in table one and four columns `(A,B,C,D)` of table two.The conditions to insert in both the tables will remain same (so no `if-else`). trigger inserts values into table project. I want to insert values 'PID' & 'PAYMENTTERM' in another table,let's say, 'temp_pay_term' as well.

Sorry, about the code missing. I'm always bad at formatting and hence i'm not able to paste the code. But it looks something like below
Create Trigger
Begin

SELECT COUNT(1)
      INTO varProjectExists
      FROM project
      WHERE ProjectUniversalID = varProject_ID;
If 
update project 
else insert into project

Now i want to insert values PID and paymentterm in another table say temp_pay_term as well

Comment: Why are you tagging with mysql?  So just perform two inserts into the two tables?  You don't show any table schemas, trigger code, etc.  How are we supposed to help you?

Comment: With what data you want to update two tables? The data comes from the table that fires the trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, with so little information I have no way to guess what you need extamante.

But following a suggestion:

```
create table TABLE1(
  "ID1"     number not null
  , "A1" varchar(20)
  , "B1" varchar(20)
  , "C1" varchar(20)
  , "D1" varchar(20)
)
/
create or replace trigger TG_BIU_TABLE1
after insert or update on TABLE1
for each row
begin
  update TABLE2
  set A2 = :new.A1
      ,B2 = :new.B1
  where TABLE2.ID2 = :new.ID1;

  update TABLE3
  set A3 = :new.A1
      ,B3 = :new.B1
      ,C3 = :new.C1
      ,D3 = :new.D1
  where TABLE3.ID3 = :new.ID1;
end;
/
create table TABLE2(
  "ID2"     number not null
  , "A2" varchar(20)
  , "B2" varchar(20)
)
/
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (ID2, A2, B2) VALUES (1, 'AAA', 'BBB')
/
create table TABLE3(
  "ID3"     number not null
  , "A3" varchar(20)
  , "B3" varchar(20)
  , "C3" varchar(20)
  , "D3" varchar(20)
)
/
INSERT INTO TABLE3 (ID3, A3, B3, C3, D3) VALUES (1, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD')
/

INSERT INTO TABLE1 (ID1, A1, B1, C1, D1) VALUES (1, 'AAA1', 'BBB1', 'CCC1', 'DDD1')
/
```